# mysqld.sock missing after server restart; MySQL server fails to start

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I manage a local intranet website which runs on Ubuntu. Now, each time I restart the server, the mysqld.sock and mysql.sock files seem to disappear. This causes the MySQL server to not start.

Is this a common problem? Each time, I have to re-install the MySQL server and client to have it appear again.

Comment: @Up_One No, I don't think I am. I just installed mysql-5.5 as it was, and am using it alongside PHPMyAdmin. Also, I just checked, and there is only one my.cnf file, though a file called debian.cnf also exists.

Comment: so no my.cnf duplicate files ?

Comment: @Up_One Nope. Only one my.cnf file.

Comment: this type of problem is when you have more then one my.cnf

Comment: last resort try to re-initialize your data directory as posted by me in the answer bellow

Comment: I've seen this problem before when the permissions are not enough to create the .pid file. Usually this is due to selinux.  As a test, chmod the directory (where the pid file should be) to allow write by the user starting mysql - then start mysql.

Comment: @FreudianSlip I've actually chmodded the directory, as well as all subdirectories/files before, but it doesn't seem to work out. I'll try it again though. I need to restart the server tomorrow, and I don't want the intranet site to be down for too long. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Of course I meant .sock file... doh.. (cant hurt to check the pid file location as well though!)

Comment: Check the logs, usually they contain more information about why the MySQL server can't start.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch Hey Isaac. Would having limited space on the server potentially cause this problem as well? Now that I look back it, when this issue was occurring, there was always very limited space available. I cleared up some space a few days ago, and after restarting the server, everything was fine.

Comment: Yes, if the drive ran out of space that could cause problems like this where services won't start. Please post back if the problem reoccurs.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch Thanks for letting me know. I'll be sure to!

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql.sock` file is created when `MariaDB` starts and is removed when `MariaDB` is shutdown. It won't exist if `MariaDB` is not running.

Multiple `my.cnf` files can conflict.
 Check to see if you have multiple `my.cnf` files on your system.
 *Possible locations include:*

- /etc/mysql/my.cnf (MariaDB default)
- /etc/my.cnf
- ~/.my.cnf

---

Try to re-initialize your data directory 'offline' using [mysql_install_db](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-install-db.html).

Answer (score 0):

For me the case was that an OS update turned `/var/run/` into temporary directory that was cleared on every restart.

Solution was to enforce recreating of `/var/run/mysqld` on every startup using one of the two methods described here: https://askubuntu.com/a/306479/567859